# Is there a way to remove characters from a string? Java

Tags: java, string, char

I am having trouble removing letters from a string. `String ALPHABET = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` User puts in a string. "klmn". How would i remove klmn from the alphabet? Is there a way? Other then putting it into an array?
This is what i started with. This only removes the last letter in the string. Whats my problem here.

```
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){



            for(int j = 0; j < ALPHABET.length(); j++){
               letter = message.charAt(i);
               if(ALPHABET.charAt(j) ==  message.charAt(i)){

                newALPHABET = ALPHABET.replace(letter, ' ');

               }               
            }
         }
```

Comment: `replace`, `replaceAll`

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you want to do but you can use [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
       alphabet = alphabet.replace("klmn","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to delete it.. the logic here is replace the char you want to delete with the next char.. and in place of second one keep the third char and so on..

if you want to delete a large length of String..
then use the method Replace..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with regular expressions. Try the next:

```
static String ALPHABET = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Letters: ");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[" + Pattern.quote(input) +"]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ALPHABET);
    String result = m.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanted to replace a character or simple substring, then `String.replace` is the solution.

If you wanted to replace matches a regex, then `String.replaceAll` is the the solution.

The reason your code is not working is because there are a couple of bugs in it:

1. You appear to be under the impression that `String.replace(char, char)` replaces a single character instance.  In fact, it replaces *all* instance of the first character in the String.
2. Each loop iteration creates a new String and assigns it to `newALPHABET`.  But then you start again with `ALPHABET` on the next iteration.

If the aim is to produce an "alphabet" that excludes the letters in `message`, then the correct solution is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    ALPHABET = ALPHABET.replace(message.charAt(i), ' ');
}
```

... except that you should NOT use `ALPHABET` as the name of a variable.  It should be `alphabet`!!!